# Remote connection to MySQL not working

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, codeigniter-2

I am facing a big problem, I have an application running with CodeIgniter and MySQL in cestacerta.com.

I have two versions, one that is in production and it works perfectly and one that is development. This runs locally on my machine and the other developers.

Well, the development version I need to remotely connect to the database. It suddenly stopped working.

I've given permission to access any IP settings on the server. I can access the database through the Mysql Gui Tools. I tested access to several different codes, including a newly downloaded version of CodeIgniter and always got the same error:

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.
>
> Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\cestacerta\system\database\DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 119

I need to know is there any test I can do what I reveal if the error is on my machine (and also the developers, because they all have the same error) or if the error is with the server I contract.

-- edit --

> $active_group = 'default';
>
> $active_record = TRUE;
>
> $db['default']['hostname'] = 'mysql.cestacerta.com';
>
> $db['default']['username'] = 'db_username';
>
> $db['default']['password'] = 'pass';
>
> $db['default']['database'] = 'db_name';
>
> $db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
>
> $db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
>
> $db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
>
> $db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
>
> $db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
>
> $db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
>
> $db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
>
> $db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
>
> $db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
>
> $db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
>
> $db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;

Comment: Please show us how did you give permission and an example (with fake data) of the configuration on codeigniter

Comment: I'd say your configs (and|or) permissions are out of sync. Start there and you'll probably identify the problem.

Comment: The server gives me the option to register to access external ips and says that if I type "%" would give him access to any ip, and that's what I do and it worked until 3 days ago. Without any modifications to the code or the database configuraçlões it stopped working.

Comment: can you get a more detailed error than what is currently being output by CI?

Comment: have you checked with cestacerta.com if they have made any changes? of if they have any more info in their logs about your connections?

Comment: The server on which I host the cestacerta.com assured me that no modification was done in php mysql or any setting these days.

I tried commands like:

tracert IP -> can not reach the server ip
telnet IP PORT -> not establish connection